# Proof by Induction - Sequence multiplication odd

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that if $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are odd numbers for $n \ge 2$
then  $X_1\cdot X_2\cdot X_3\cdot...\cdot X_n$ is also odd.
I made equation $X_n=2_X(n)+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Start with basic $n = 2$ : 
$X_1,X_2$ will be odd numbers then:
$X_1\cdot X_2=(2X_1+1) \cdot (2X_2+1)=4X_1 X_2+2X_1+2X_2+1=2(2X_1 X_2+X_1+X_2 )+1$

when $n = k$
$X_1,X_2,…,X_k-odd→X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot X_3,\ldots X_k-odd$

Now need to prove that if $X_1,X_2,…,X_(k+1)$ then its multiplication odd
$X_1*X_2*X_3,…*X_k=X_m$
and now have to prove that $X_m*X_(k+1) $  odd?
but is the same as I show in the base case $n=2$ (multiplication of odd numbers)

any idea? :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking or what your confusion is.  $X_m$ is odd and $X_{k+1}$ is odd.  And you've already proven the product of two odd numbers is odd. So $X_m*X_{k+1}$ is odd. So... what's your question?

Comment: my answers is correct? its seems that the basic of checking induction $(n=2)$ already proof my induction .. isnt contradicts the structure of induction answer?

Comment: No, you need the inductive step that says if $X_1*... *X_k$ is odd then $X_1*... X_{k+1}$ is odd.  The induction step is simple noting that $x_1*...*X_k$ is itself a single odd number and so $(X_1*.....*X_k)*X_{k+1}$ is not just $k+1$ odd numbers but are also simply *two* odd numbers.  ANother way do it is $X_1 *.....*X_{k-1}*X_k*X_{k+1} = X_1*....*X_{k_1}*(X_k*X_{k+1})$ and $(X_{k}*X_{k+1}$ is a single odd number and $ X_1*....*X_{k_1}*(X_k*X_{k+1})$ is not just a product of $k+1$ odds; it's product of $k$ odd.

Comment: The induction step is $X_1*X_2*....*X_k = M$ is odd.  So $X_1*X_2*....*X_k*X_{k+1} = M*X_{k+1}$.  You can't avoid stating that.  But when you say $M$ and $X_{k+1}$ are two odd numbers there is absolutely no need to prove that two odd numbers will result in an odd number *again*.  Just note that in the base case we saw that results in an odd number.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You proved the base case so then you assume that X1 * X2 * ... * Xk is odd and try to prove that X1 * X2 * ... * Xk * X(k+1) is also odd.

You have to use your assumption that X1 * X2 * ... * Xk is odd which means that X1 * X2 * ... * Xk = 2n+1 where n is some integer. X(k+1) is also odd which is from the description of the problem so X(k+1) = 2m+1 where m is some integer.

So for the k+1 case, you substitute (2n+1) for X1 * X2 * ... * Xk and (2m+1) for X(k+1) and then need to prove (2n+1)(2m+1) is odd

(2n+1)(2m+1) = 4m*n+2m+2n+1

= 2[2mn+m+n]+1 
Which is odd

In other words you pretty much prove it in the exact same way as the base case when n=2.

Comment: Except you *don't* need to prove two odd numbers multiply to an odd number because you already *did* that in the base case.